# How to resolve Only public methods can be invoked in the background in hangfire?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have method in `class` which is `public`. When I add it to hangfire I got compiler error

> Only public methods can be invoked in the background. Ensure your
>   method has the `public` access modifier, and you aren't using explicit
>   interface implementation.'

```
  public class JobsService
    {
        public void TestJob2(Parameters parameters)
        {
        }
    }

    public class JobsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly JobsService _jobsService;

        public JobsController(JobsService jobsService)
        {
            _jobsService = jobsService;
        }

       public IActionResult AddOrUpdate([FromQuery]string recurringJobId = "", [FromQuery]string methodName = "", [FromQuery] bool remove = false, [FromQuery] string cronExpression = "*/1 * * * *", [FromBody] Parameters parameters = null)
       {
          Expression<Action> expression = ToExpression(() => { string t = (string)method.Invoke(_jobsService, new object[] { parameters }); });
          RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(recurringJobId, expression, cronExpression);
       }
    }
```

Comment: your `class` is `public` but what about your `method` ? is it `public` too? in hangfire, only methods with `public access modifier` could be scheduled

Comment: My method is  public void TestJob2

Comment: You should call your method according to this official sample: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/samples/ConsoleSample/Program.cs#L19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda and its parameters need to be serializable by Hangfire. AFAIK, its body must be a simple call, no method assignment for example.

The `JobsService` instance performing the job can't be the one referenced by your controller. I assume you have set up Hangfire for dependency injection [see "Using IoC containers"](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html), or `JobsService` can be instantiated without needing any dependency [see "Passing dependencies"](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html).

You need to add a method to your `JobsService` class :

```
public void InvokeMethod(string methodName, Parameters parameters)
{
    MethodInfo mi = typeof(JobsService).GetMethod(methodName);
    string s = (string)mi.Invoke(this, new[] { parameters });
}
```

Then, your `JobsController` `AddOrUpdate` method would be :

```
public IActionResult AddOrUpdate([FromQuery]string recurringJobId = "",[FromQuery]string methodName = "", [FromQuery] bool remove = false, [FromQuery] string cronExpression = "*/1 * * * *", [FromBody] Parameters parameters = null)
{
  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<JobsService>(
           recurringJobId, 
           js => js.InvokeMethod(methodName, parameters), 
           () => cronExpression
           );
}
```